# MemcacheD multiple data saves per second

Tags: php, laravel, memcached

**Happy Friday fellow Stack Overflow users!**

Let me kind of set the scene here a bit:

I have an application that records users actions into MemcacheD with the following code:

```
<?php
    // This tracks a users actions for 24 hours
    function listActions($user){
        $minutes = 1440;    $total
        $actionsCache = Cache::remember('userActions', $minutes, function() use($total) {
            $array = [100, 140, 523, 10, 109]; // example list of user ID's
            $ar = [];
            foreach($array as $p){
                $array[$p] = [];
            }
            return $ar;
        });
        return $actionsCache;
    }
?>
```

Then, every time a user does an action in the site, it is recorded using:

```
<?php
    // This records a new action and then saves it to the userActions cache
    function saveAction($action, $user){
        $minutes = 1440;
        $Cache = Cache::get('userActions');
        $Cache[$user][time()] = $action;
        Cache::put('userActions', $Cache, $minutes);
        return $Cache[$user];
    }

?>
```

This is a simplified form of what is going on, but it illustrates my point well.

**My issue**: It appears as though some of these actions aren't being recorded. These actions happen relatively fast and the same Cache variable is manipulated for each action on each user (as seen above)

**My question**: could it be possible that the code is not grabbing the latest Cache value, ergo saving over an old value?

Comment: It's entirely possible. It's called a race condition.

Comment: @jszobody - what should I do in this situation? Do you think that grabbing the Cache value right before saving would help alleviate this situation?

Comment: I don't think storing a massive array in cache is a good solution at all. Requires retrieving, parsing, modifying, restoring the huge array every single time. Find a way to only create _new_ action records, without needing to retrieve or modify existing records.

Comment: @jszobody some of these actions can only be done once a day

Comment: How is that applicable?

Comment: You need a way to just append new actions. I think a database is probably going to be your best fit, where you can simple insert new rows for each action. Even sqlite would work a lot better than this.

Comment: I agree with @jszobody, however I would use redis for this if I could - it's built for High Availability non-blocking I/O storage, which is basically exactly what you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up fixing this issue by switching over to `redis`, as it has locking built in.

If I had stayed with `MemcacheD` (which I did for a while) I would have implemented a lock on the data structure itself so it could not be edited while another process was utilizing it (mainly, anything that would have read AND wrote to the data, would have needed to lock the data).

I hope this helps anyone that may come by this!